# Multiple Custom Post Types Relationship URL

Tags: wordpress

I have got a unique situation where I am dealing with 3 Custom post types.

```
#1- Course - (For example "XYZ")
#2- Chapter - (For example "Basic")
#3- Lesson - (For example "Lesson1")
```

I know about the "slug" rewrite when declaring custom post types. However, I want these to appear like this.

```
/course/XYZ/ (To show Course)
/course/XYZ/chapter/basic/ (To show Chapter)
/course/XYZ/chapter/basic/lesson/lession1 (To show lesson)
```

Also, another way I can get this is by.

```
/course/XYZ/ (To show Course)
/course/XYZ/basic/ (To show Chapter)
/course/XYZ/basic/lession1 (To show lesson)
```

Just need the URL structure to work, I will be setting query to show chapter and lessons for each course.

Comment: Hello Ahmed, Maybe you need another approach to solve this. I suggest just one CPT i.e. Lessons , then add all lessons into this CPT. Then have a two taxonomies, Courses and Chapters and then tag each CPT lesson into related Chapter,Course.. then you can query the taxonomy for the course and chapters in it and show lessons...

Comment: Yeah, that can be one solution but the reason I have this as custom posts is to have control over adding a lot of options for each post type, something I cant do with a taxonomy category.